# Java Chat Server that can read and write messages

Tags: java

I tried to make an Server that can send and recieve messages to multiple Clients. But i have the problem that the client does not even send the message to the server i wish to. I did not already added the writing part of the Server, i now just try to make the Server read messages from the client. Thanks for any Help. Here is my Server and my Client:

```
public class Main {


public static ArrayList<PrintWriter> writers = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(9898);
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket client = sock.accept();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
                writers.add(writer);
                Thread t = new Thread(new Handler(client));
                t.start();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Server Started");
}
```

}

```
public class Handler implements Runnable {
private Socket client;

public Handler(Socket client) {
    this.client = client;
}
@Override
public void run() { 
    try {
        //Streams---------------------------------
        OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);

        InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  
        //----------------------------------------


        String s = null;
        while(true) {
            if((s=reader.readLine()) != null) {
        }       System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

public class Manager implements Runnable {

```
Socket sockel;
String pcname = System.getProperty("user.name");
BufferedReader reader;
PrintWriter writer;
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        sockel = new Socket("localhost", 9898);
        //Streams
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sockel.getInputStream()));
        writer = new PrintWriter(sockel.getOutputStream());
        //--------------
        System.out.println("Connected to: " + sockel.getInetAddress());
        writer.write("hello");
        writer.flush();
        System.out.println("here");
        String command = reader.readLine();
        while(!command.equalsIgnoreCase("close" + pcname)) {
            System.out.println("Got Message: " + command);
        }
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any Exception ?

Comment: You are like "code not working. here code" ... and now what? We spent the time reading your code, maybe running, to figure *what* the problem to then fix the problem for you? Sorry, but this is not how this site works. And the whole idea of learning programming is *about spending that time it takes to understand problems and fix them*. You are trying to delegate **all** of that pesky work to other people. And hint: that *preview* functionality exists for a reason - so that you can check the formatting of your input **prior** sending it to us.

Comment: “But i have the problem that the client does not even send the message to the server i wish to.” How do you know that?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the class Manager.
you have to create two project one client and another server and start the server project and after that start the client.

I hope that this is helped you.